# Hide item when background container is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Everything is perfect about this menu I am creating except for one thing. When a primary navigation item is clicked and the sub menu opens the only way to get the submenu to close is by clicking the same primary navigation item again. I would like to make it so the submenu will close if the user clicks anywhere else within the main popover.

Please see the below code snippet for my exact code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


  <!--MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE -->

  <style>
    /* main menu */
    .mainNav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100px;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: normal;
      width: 368px;
      display: block;
      cursor: default;
    }
    .mainNav-item {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .mainNav-item a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile {
      display: block;
      margin: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: normal;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      background: transparent;
      border-width: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      outline-color: #e7e7e7;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile:hover {
      outline-color: #ccc;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile-img {
      display: block;
      padding: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .popover {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: auto;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1000;
      left: 80px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
  </style>



  <div style="float: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 13px 15px 0 0">
    <img data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmousedown="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none;">
      <div>
        <ul class="mainNav">
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem1</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content1' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem2</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content2' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem3</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content3' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem4</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content4' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem5</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content5' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                    html: true,
                    content: function () {
                        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                    }
                });

                $('html').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $(this).popover('hide');
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("html").on("click", ".dropdown", function (e) {
                    var $this = $(this).children(".dropdown-content");

                    if ($this.find("a").length > 0) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $(".dropdown-content:visible").not($this).slideToggle(200); //Close submenu already opened
                        $this.slideToggle(200); //Open the new submenu
                    }
                });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Set this up in a fiddle, like jsfiddle.org and post a link

Comment: So you want to click on the empty space in the menu that contains the five items and be able to close the popover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the close event to the parent on click and stop event propagation when the children are clicked.

Add this to your code:

```
$('html').on('click', ".mainNav", function(e) {
    $(".dropdown-content:visible").slideToggle(200);
});
```

And add `e.stopPropagation();` under:

```
$("html").on("click", ".dropdown", function(e) {
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b9k59a65/)

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. Any idea why when I click one of the anchors in the submenu I do not navigate anywhere? is something possibly cancelling it?

Comment: Yup, its because of the `e.preventDefault();` in your code that triggers when links are found

Comment: Thanks! I ended up figuring it out creating another $("html").on("click", ".dropdown-content a", function(e) { to stop propagation if an anchor tag is actually clicked making it never bubble up to the event that handles the opening and closing of the submenu.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional `if` to handle this.

```
if(!$(e.target).parents('.dropdown').length){
    $('.dropdown-content').hide();
}
```

This says, "if the parents of the thing that is clicked has a `dropdown` class, then hide any `.dropdown-content`'s".

You could change the `hide` to be a `slideUp`, or whatever you like.

The code you've posted could do with optimising. It's bad practice to hook up events to `$(document)` or `<html>` - you should be attaching it to the lowest-level element you know will be there. For you, this could at least be `ul.mainNav`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


  <!--MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE -->

  <style>
    /* main menu */
    .mainNav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100px;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: normal;
      width: 368px;
      display: block;
      cursor: default;
    }
    .mainNav-item {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .mainNav-item a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile {
      display: block;
      margin: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: normal;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      background: transparent;
      border-width: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      outline-color: #e7e7e7;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile:hover {
      outline-color: #ccc;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile-img {
      display: block;
      padding: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .popover {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: auto;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1000;
      left: 80px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
  </style>



  <div style="float: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 13px 15px 0 0">
    <img data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmousedown="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none;">
      <div>
        <ul class="mainNav">
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem1</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content1' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem2</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content2' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem3</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content3' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem4</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content4' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem5</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content5' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                    html: true,
                    content: function () {
                        return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
                    }
                });

                $('html').on('click', function (e) {
                   if(!$(e.target).parents('.dropdown').length){
                        $('.dropdown-content').hide();
                   }
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $(this).popover('hide');
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("html").on("click", ".dropdown", function (e) {
                    var $this = $(this).children(".dropdown-content");

                    if ($this.find("a").length > 0) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $(".dropdown-content:visible").not($this).slideToggle(200); //Close submenu already opened
                        $this.slideToggle(200); //Open the new submenu
                    }
                });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your javascript code inside $(document).ready()

```
$("html").on("click", ".mainNav", function (e) {
    if(e.target.className == "mainNav"){
        $(".dropdown-content:visible").slideToggle(200);
    }
});
```